# Can I bridge C inline functions to Swift?

Tags: c, swift, function, inline, bridging-header

If I put an inline function in a .h file, then include that in the bridging header, can I invoke it in Swift? (Answer: Yes) But will it still be inline when invoked in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will do what it wants but generally the answer is **yes**. This is part of why the atomics libraries and math shims that go down to C use header only inlined modules. So at least in release builds it can be fully optimized.

See [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/tree/main/Sources/_NumericsShims) for example.